# strcmp() doesnt return 0 even both strings are equal

Tags: c, newline, c-strings, fgets

im new into programming and one of my assignments is to build a login system in c, where the username and the password are stored inside a .txt file, the .txt file looks like this

> danielR
>
> 77bd

(top is the username and below is the password)

the problem is when I compare the two strings from user input and from the .txt file of both username and password using strcmp(), it doesnt return to 0 even tho both strings are equal

```
#include <stdio.h)
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct login 
{
char name[25];
char pass[25];
};
void login()
{
struct login acc1,acc2;
printf("input your username : ");
scanf ("%s",acc1.name);
printf("input your password : ");
scanf ("%s",acc1.pass);
FILE* fp = fopen("account.txt","r");
fgets(acc2.name,25,fp);
fgets(acc2.pass,25,fp);
if (strcmp(acc1.name,acc2.name)==0 && strcmp(acc1.pass,acc2.pass)==0)
{
printf("login successful\n");
}
else
{
printf("wrong password or username");
}
```

I've even tried using printf to match the usernames and passwords from userinput and from .txt files and they all are equal. I wonder why strcmp() doesnt return to 0. any help?

Comment: `fgets` will read and append the `\n` character to the string. You need to strip it off before comparison. Also I suggest to use `fgets` for user input instead of `scanf` too

Comment: Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: Note; `scanf ("%s",acc1.pass);` will not allow spaces as part of `acc1.pass` nor does it cope with long input.   Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fgets` can append the input string with the new line character `'\n'`  provided that the destination array has enough space.

You need to remove it.

You can do it for example the following way

```
acc2.name[ strcspn( acc2.name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
acc2.pass[ strcspn( acc2.pass, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

after these calls

```
fgets(acc2.name,25,fp);
fgets(acc2.pass,25,fp);
```

Pay attention to that it will be more safer to initialize data members at least of the object `acc1`.

For example

```
struct login acc1 = { .name = "", .pass = "" };
struct login acc2;
```

and you should check that the file was opened successfully and calls of `fgets` also were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [`fgets`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), it considers new lines valid characters and stores them in your string buffer. Reduce the length of your string by one to offset it.